# Why does this number gets detected as bool?

Tags: c#, if-statement, numbers, operators, relational

I'm checking if value ir between 0 and -0.2 like so:

```
float value = -0.1;
if (0 < value > -0.2f) { }
```

But I get error `operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'float'`. I know, I could to that in other way using `&&` operator in that if sentence, but I want to know, **why** does it gets detected as bool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
0 < value > -0.2f
```

Firstly `0 < value` is evaluated, it returns `bool` value then it tries it compare `bool` to float number `-0.2f`, so it returns error, because it is not permitted.

You want to check if value is less and if value is greater than, so this is what you want to do:

```
if (0 < value && value > -0.2f) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
float value = -0.1;
if (0 < value > -0.2f) { }
```

Because you need to seperate the comparisons

Most langauges work left to right so

```
0 < value
```

will be evaluated first. The result of this a boolean

Now your expression reads as

```
boolean > -0.2f
```

Which obviously will not work. You need

```
if (0 < value && value > -0.2f)
```

&& is a 'logical and' which combines the results of the logical computation to the left and right of it

Comment: No-one seems to have noticed that if `0 < value` then `value > 0` (unless value is NaN) therefore `value > -0.2f`, so either the OP has an unnecessary test or meant to test the range `(( 0.0f > value ) && ( value > -0.2f ))`

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the construction of your if statement. Try this instead:

```
if (0 < value && value > -0.2f) { }
```

What you've written is equivalent to this:

```
if ((0 < value) > -0.2f) { }
```

The `0 < value` comparison is being evaluated, returning a boolean, which then becomes the operand for the second comparison. And, as the error message says, you can't use `>` to compare a boolean and a float.

Answer (score 0):

Because of **order of operations**.

Basically, the compiler compile the if to something like this:

```
if ((0 < value) > -0.2f)
```

And the result of that is comparing a `bool` and an `int`, which is not good.

Try this instead:

```
if (0 < value && value > 0.2f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is syntactically incorrect. It requires a boolean expression between the braces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5011f09h.aspx

```
if (0 < value > -0.2f) { }
```

Your statement is parsed like this:

```
if ((0 < value) > -0.2f) { }
```

`(0 < value)` evaluates to boolean expression. You're attempting to compare this to a float. Hence the error.

As you suggested yourself, the normal way to do this is to use `&&`.